# bash script to combine image stacks. Command does not exist

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script to combine all my images in IMOD. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $IMOD_DIR/IMOD-linux.sh
#image folder
cd raw_data
if [ ! -f *.mdoc ];then
echo 'You need at least one mdoc file !'
else
for mdoc in *.mdoc
do
filename=`basename ${mdoc} .st.mdoc`
gawk '/SubFramePath/{print $0}' < $mdoc | cut -d "\\" -f 4 >test.txt
mrcfile=`cat test.txt`
#combine stack
newstack ${mrcfiles} ${filename}.mrcs
rm -r test.txt
done
fi
```

However, it raised two errors. One is line 4 (when I try to test if mdoc file exists in the folder), "expecting a binary operator".And line 9 (when I passed the basename to the variable $filename, it says command not found. 
I am confused what I did wrong?

Comment: For the first error, try using `if` condition with double brackets: `if [[ ! -f *.mdoc ]]`. For the second error, can you check the `basename` utility by using `which basename`,if it exists in your system?

Comment: @User123 Double or single brackets shouldn't make a difference here, but using `*.mdoc` is a problem if it expands to more than one file.

Comment: @User123, the basename did exist. Because I can see the output when I just typed in bash by assigning $mdoc with a specific file. I wonder if the problem was raised under for loop.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have more than one mdoc and I want to go through each of them,since each record different images information. Could you explain more by what you mean "*.mdoc is a problem if it expands to more than one file"?

Comment: If `*.mdoc` expands to more than one doc, you'll have `[ ! -f x.mdoc y.mdoc ]`, and `[ ]` will choke, as `-f` accepts just a single argument.